# error playing stream on android 9 and 10 with exoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, ogg

```
String prp = "http://stream.dedyn.io:8000/dsbmradio.opus";
```

it works until android 8, but it doesn't work on 9 or 10. follow the code I'm using

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(prp);
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

this is the error generated

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://rfmbrasil.servemp3.com:8000/uespi.ogg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using "http" url you are not able to play video in android 9 and above.

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Have a look at below answer for more info

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/7398620

Comment: I had already solved with just android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" enables all http urls to run in your app. You should create a network_security_config.xml file and add trusted IP in that such as like your server IP etc.